# Android webview zoomed to show all page content

Tags: android, webview

I have just started out in Android development and I can't find a satisfactory answer to this question anywhere.

I am trying to build an Android tablet app to display this webpage (https://www.megaseatingplan.com/app/edit-seating-app.php) in a webview. The size of the content on the page will vary by user. I would like all of the content to appear in the webview without any scrolling.

So far, I've used `myWebView.getSettings().setUseWideViewPort(true);` and     `myWebView.getSettings().setLoadWithOverviewMode(true);` to fit the page to the width of the webview. This works nicely, but I need it to do the equivalent thing for the height of the page.

Any ideas? I obviously have access to the code of the webpage I'm loading, so a solution on either then web end or the app end would work for me.

Thank you.

Comment: To set the layout of Html inside web view you need to set LayoutAlgorithm to webSetting . Please have a look at below this [link](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebSettings.html#setLayoutAlgorithm(android.webkit.WebSettings.LayoutAlgorithm)) .

Answer (score 0):

```
webView.getSettings().setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
```

If you need more advance webView you can use webview sample.

In order to enable zoom on the webView, add the following code in onTuchEvent override method:

```
webview.getSettings().setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
webview.getSettings().setSupportZoom(true);
```

If your webview goes to another url and you want to mantain the zoom level use the webSettings class

```
webview.getSettings().setDefaultZoom(WebSettings.ZoomDensity.FAR);
```

If you want a pre-defined zoom when webview loads use:

`mWebView.setInitialScale(ZOOM_LEVEL);`  // int value 50 = 50% -- 200 = 200%
It works pretty well for all device resolutions.

OR

```
public class Main extends Activity {
  private WebView myWebView;
  private static final FrameLayout.LayoutParams ZOOM_PARAMS = new FrameLayout.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,Gravity.BOTTOM);

      @Override
      protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        this.setContentView(R.layout.webview);
        this.myWebView = (WebView) this.findViewById(R.id.webView);

        FrameLayout mContentView = (FrameLayout) getWindow().
        getDecorView().findViewById(android.R.id.content);
        final View zoom = this.myWebView.getZoomControls();
        mContentView.addView(zoom, ZOOM_PARAMS);
        zoom.setVisibility(View.GONE);

        this.myWebView.loadUrl("http://www.facebook.com");
      }
    }
```